# Reduce my two mysql calls to one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Using codeigniter (php) I want to go to a table called task get the most recent result in the table and add data from that row to an array that I pass to the view. I have an ugly hack to make this work (shown below). Basically I am going to the table asking for the most recent date and then using this to  query the table again for the data I want. Ideally this should be one call to the database.

Also ideally I would like to be able to retrieve everything from the table row rather than just one column as I have here - simple enough to do in the model but confusing me how I integrate this in the controller so that the returned array integrates with the array sent to the view

controller:

```
public function index()
{   
    //Load models
    $this->load->model('project_model');
    $this->load->model('task_model');

    $flasks = $this->task_model->get_user_tasks_two($this->session->userdata('user'));

    foreach($flasks as $key => $value){
        //get last task
        $task2 = $this->task_model->get_last_task_date($value['project_id']);

        $task3 = $this->task_model->get_last_task_details($task2 , $value['project_id']);
        $flasks[$key]['flask_type'] = $task3;

    }
    $data['tasks'] = $flasks;

    // Load View
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);

}
```

model:

```
public function get_user_tasks_two($user)
{
    $this->db->select(' project.id as project_id, project.name as project_name, project.archive as project_archive');
    $this->db->from('project');
    $this->db->join('user_project', 'project.id = user_project.project AND user_project.user = '.$user.'');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'asc');
    $get = $this->db->get();

    if($get->num_rows > 0) return $get->result_array();
    return array();
}

public function get_last_task_date($id)
{
    $this->db->select_max('date_created');
    $this->db->from('task');
    $this->db->where('project_id', $id);

    $get = $this->db->get();
    $ret = $get->row();
    return $ret->date_created;
}

public function get_last_task_details($date, $id)
{
    $this->db->select('user_name');  
    $this->db->from('task');
    $this->db->where('date_created', $date);
    $this->db->where('project_id', $id);

    $get = $this->db->get();
    $ret = $get->row();
    return $ret->user_name;
}
```

Comment: do you want to get recent tasks from task table for each project?

Comment: yep, the most recent task for each project. The view is going to list the projects in order and also give the details of the most recent task in that project. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

First try this query in your phpmyadmin / mysql tool

```
select 
        p.id as project_id, 
        p.name as project_name, 
        p.archive as project_archive,
            t.task_name, 
            t.user_name,
            t.date_created
from 
        project p 
join 
            task t 
on 
           p.id=t.project_id and    
           t.id> (
               select id from tasks  where t.project_id = p.id order by id DESC LIMIT 1
               )
```

Comment: I tweaked this a bit and it functions but its not what I am looking for as it does not involve the user_name but maybe your were planning on looking that up in a second step? `SELECT p.id AS project_id, p.name AS project_name, p.archive AS project_archive, t.task_id, t.date_created
FROM project p
JOIN task t ON p.id = t.project_id
AND t.task_id > ( 
SELECT task_id
FROM task
WHERE t.project_id = p.id
ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: as per your coding `function get_last_task_details`,  are you storing user name in task table? or username coming from user table?

Comment: User_name is from task table

Comment: Ah. I see. Will try this later today